# TinyMCE: how to center an image?

Tags: tinymce

In TinyMCE, I may insert an image and center it. And the code generated is as follows:

```
<p><img height="684" src="/static/media/uploads/about.jpg" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;" width="938" /></p>
```

However, when I save the textarea, the `display: block;` style is removed.

I also tried the followings, but all in vain:

1. Set `<p>`:

   ```
   <p style="text-align: center;"><img ... ></p>
   ```

   The style of `<p>` is removed when I save the content of the textarea.
2. In `tinymce.init`, set:

   ```
   verify_html: false
   ```
3. Set `valid_children: "+body[style]"` in `tiymce.init` and add the following in textarea:

   ```
   <style>
   p img {
     display: block;
   }
   </style>
   ```
4. Set the following in tinymce.init:

   ```
   valid_styles: {
       "img": "display"
   }
   ```

So, how do I center an image in TinyMCE anyway?

Comment: Is this really a tough question? In that case, maybe the question should be "how do I set TinyMCE not to parse the style settings"?

Comment: I just tried your example and it works for me. The image is centered. Are you sure you are running the last version?

Comment: @devconcept same for me - what Version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a work-around solution:

Modify `tinymce.init`:

(a) Add Formats: add the class `center` and necessary `styles` to every centered block element including `img`.

```
formats: {
    aligncenter: {selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'center',
                  styles: {display: 'block', margin: '0px auto', textAlign: 'center'}},
}
```

(b) Add JavaScript to display centered elements correctly in the editing window: replace previously added `margin: 0px auto;` with `margin: 0px auto; display:block; text-align: center;`:

```
var value = $('textarea').val();
value = value.replace('margin: 0px auto;', 'margin: 0px auto; display:block; text-align: center;');
$('textarea').val(value);
```

And then add the following in our own CSS file to display centered element correctly in the HTML page:

```
.center {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The above solution took me hours to figure it out, all because TinyMCE wouldn't want to save the style `display: block;` created by its own!

Answer (score 4):

**Edit CSS**

If you are able to insert css to your page, you could simply set the images property to `display: block`:

```
p img {
    display: block;
}
```

**Edit TinyMCE**

If you are not able to excess the css files , you can maybe somehow edit the TinyMCE editor, so that you are able to use its build in `text-align: center` button, which should do the same, as your code does?

You can set the toolbar of your TinyMCE like so:

```
$('#your_editor').tinymce({
    plugins: 'link,code,preview,autolink',             
    height: 350,
    width: 750,
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link image | preview code"
});
```

Within `toolbar:` you can choose which buttons you want to add. Using `aligncenter` you can create a button, which you can use to align your image to the center.

Comment: Centering the image has no problem in the editor. The problem is that when I `save` the textarea, some of the styles will be removed, for example, `display: block;`.

Comment: Even if you do not use custom styles, that you have added, but use the build in tinymce functions?

Comment: Same. I have edited my question: tinymce will add `display: block;` automatically when I choose to center the image. But it will be remove when I save the content.

Comment: This is a noob guess, but just to be sure: Have you tried to apply `display: block` inside your `<style>img {}</style>` using `!important`? So: `img {display: block !important;}`

Comment: @yltang52 although, maybe you are able to send a live link to your website? That would help looking for the error! All basic tinymce build ups work like a charm using only one of your tweaks you have tried.

Comment: The whole `<style>` are removed. But if I add `valid_children: "+body[style]"` in `tinymce.init`, the `<style>` element becomes comments `<!--`.

Comment: @yltang52 are you able to insert <style> somewhere outside of your tinymce editor (in one of the core files of the website?) or are you able to insert `jquery` anywhere? Then we could append the styles using jQuery instead of a css file!

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Because, it's a Mezzanine CMS, users may choose to align the image to the left, center, or right. Currently, left and right are OK; only center has problem.

Comment: You always can set the align to `left` or `right`, while "hardcode" a fix into the core files. This should not affect each other.